# como extraer array dentro de objeto para mostrar en una lista

Tags: angular, angular-material

Tengo un objeto con la siguiente estructura:

```
[
   {
      "id":"1322",
      "descripcion":"Valido",
      "valores":[
         {
            "descripcion":"Agrego con Validacion",
            "var":"55"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":"2555",
      "descripcion":"Estado",
      "valores":[
         {
            "descripcion":"proceso",
            "valor":"P"
         },
         {
            "descripcion":"Otro",
            "valor":"O"
         },
         {
            "descripcion":"Ausente",
            "valor":"A"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

necesito extraer solo valores para mostrar en una lista de material de angular al intentar hacer
`const lista =objeto.valores` esta undefined, al intentar hacer map me dice que map no es una funcion de objeto, lo mismo pasa con reduce, solo necesito el array de valores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes obtener todos los `valores` con la funcion [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce).

```js
let datos = [{
    "id": "1322",
    "descripcion": "Valido",
    "valores": [{
      "descripcion": "Agrego con Validacion",
      "var": "55"
    }]
  },
  {
    "id": "2555",
    "descripcion": "Estado",
    "valores": [{
        "descripcion": "proceso",
        "valor": "P"
      },
      {
        "descripcion": "Otro",
        "valor": "O"
      },
      {
        "descripcion": "Ausente",
        "valor": "A"
      }
    ]
  }
]

let listaDeValores = datos.reduce((a, b) => a = a.concat(b.valores), [])

console.log(listaDeValores)
```

Comment: excelente trabajo muy bien para mi!muchas gracias.